# best VNC Server for Linux?

Tags: vnc

I know this may be a question about personal preferences.

But, in terms of: speed / memory usage / ease of configuration/ licensing , which is the best VNC server you know?

I have tried TightVNC, TigerVNC, UltraVNC and RealVNC , but right now I can't figure out which one is the best (any of these I listed or any other) in terms of what I worried about right now (speed/consumption/config/licensing).

What are your best choices?

Comment: This is very subjective and a "moving target" as well when each of the respective authors are continually adding additional features/functionality.

Comment: Please read FAQ, or at least the part about "What kind of questions should I not ask here?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

well, TurboVNC has VirtualGL support. This allows hardware acceleration over VNC, and has been one of the only two killer features I've ever seen in a VNC client/server. Of course, you have to SSH tunnel it to make it secure... The second was X11vnc's ability to attach to native X screens or virtual framebuffers.

[This comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Features) might help you out; if you can't narrow down by features then they all should pretty much meet your needs.

Answer (score 10):

I've honestly had terrible success with VNC servers on Linux lately. In response, I've switched to often just using X-forwarding to run stuff remotely..

To try it, from another Linux machine, you can quickly (usually) get going by adding "-X" when sshing in:

```
$ ssh -X me@myserverbox
```

Once you've logged in remotely, you can run apps over the network just by calling them up:

```
$ xclock
```

If everything's well, you'll see xclock appear locally, but it'll be running from the machine you sshed in to.

You can actually run entire window manager sessions over this.. But it's a bit of effort and you definitely want a really nice network for it.

You CAN also run X servers on Windows, so you can Xhost apps over in to windows - and to do it in OSX, you have to install X11, run it and then ssh in from a terminal running on X11.

Hope that helps ya a bit.

Edited: To correct terminology error

Comment: It's true that works, (although you shouldn't call it xhosting, that implies the horrific `xhost <server>` mechanism). The proper term is X forwarding, or X11-forwarding if you're feeling fancy. Beware of apps that need trusted X11 connections and the ssh clients that support them: if supported, you might need `-Y` instead or your windows will be blank. had it happen with Java GUIs. For Windows, the best X server is probably [Xming](http://xming.sf.net).

Comment: I know about X11-forwarding (and once upon a time I also have managed to use it with Cygwin in Windows!), but currently is not my desired solution. Anyway thank you!

Comment: The TurboVNC suggestion above sounds pretty shiney and fun. I'll have to give that a whirl!

Answer (score 6):

I've tried several VNC Server on linux and for me the better server is [X11VNC](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) .

X11VNC is lightweight stable VNC Server that have a lot of options and allow a great integration with UltraVNC client.

Comment: +1 x11vnc every time, it "just works"!

Answer (score 2):

I currently have a Linux server and to dial into that I'm using NoMachineNX/FreeNX, it uses SSH (Port 22) to connect, it may be worth giving it a go. I can't exactly remember how I set it up, but it did involve some googling.

http://www.nomachine.com/

http://freenx.berlios.de/

Comment: FreeNX uses SSH on port 22, not SSL.

Comment: @joet3ch - Yep you're correct, my bad